# Is it pssible to use generic protocols in viewcontrollers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to create a generic TableViewController for selecting any data that conforms  to `Equatable` protocol, so when I need to have a ViewController to select some equatable data, I just create a ViewController that inherits the generic TableViewController.

What I'm thinking is:

Create a generic tableviewcontroller

```
// Example of any Equatable data types
struct Student: Equatable {
...
}

class GenericDataSelectionViewController<T: Equatable>: UITableViewController {
    var items: [T] = []
    ...
}
```

and write all other basic codes for displaying and selceting data, so when I need a viewcontroller to select `Student` data, I just create a new viewcontroller:

```
class SelectStudentViewController: GenericDataSelectionViewController<Student>
```

When I need to call this vc to select a student, I just do

```
class fooViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func selectStudent() {
        let destVC = SelectStudentViewController()
        destVC.items = students
        // show destVC ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But in order to get the selected data, I also need a generic protocol, so I create a protocol:

```
protocol DataSelectionProtocol: class {
    associatedtype T: Equatable
    func didSelect(_ option: T)
}
```

So in the generic vc, I create a variable

```
weak var delegate: DataSelectionProtocol?
```

and inside the `selectStudent()` function above, I add `destVC.delegate = self` and implement `fooViewController` to conform to `DataSelectionProtocol` and use `didSelect` function to handle the selected student data.

But I get a `Protocol 'DataSelectionProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` error when a add the `delegate` variable in generic tableviewcontroller.

So is this the correct way to do it? Or I need to create another protocol that conforms to `DataSelectionProtocol` for selecting student (but I feel this is not the correct way as I would have to create new protocols for new data types, and this is not so 'Generic')?

Comment: @matt Yes the tableviewcontroller can select data of any equatable type. But what I also need is to pass the selected datat back to the vc that called the tableviewcontroller and handle the selected data in that vc. So what I want to do is to create a generic protocol for passing and handling any kind of selected `Equatable` data. And also the app is not just for iOS 13.

Comment: It would be simpler to use a closure instead of a delegate to pass the selection back

Comment: You can not use protocols with associated types for delegates. They are just another way of describing a concrete dataType in this case like Int, Float etc whatever conforms to Equatable Protocol.

Comment: @dan Yes there are other ways to pass and handle data, but I wonder what's the best way to do it using protocols.

Comment: @ShreeramBhat So that meas I still have to create a protocol that conforms to the generic protocol for `Student` in my case?